# Show all records in database with MSSQL

Tags: android, sql-server

I created an application and the one error i am getting when i click my run button is that it only displays my last record in my database while i want it to show all the records and not just one record.

Here is my code:

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            con = connectionclass();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Check Your internet Access!";
            } else {
                String query = "select * from mo_test";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    name1 = rs.getString("username");
                    name2 = rs.getString("fName");

                }
                z = "query successful";
                isSuccess = true;
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            z = ex.getMessage();

            Log.d("Sql error", z);

        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

So i basically want to display all my usernames together and all my first names together, but it is only showing the last records username and first name. How do i solve this?

Comment: I don't know anything about android development but look at your loop. You set the name1 and name2 variables to a new value each iteration through the loop. Since you are doing nothing else inside your loop it is going to overwrite the value in your variables each iteration. You need to do something with the value inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the `while loop` you put the values from your `ResultSet` in two of your local variables. For every record it will override it. So the values of the first row go into variable `name1` and `name2`. The second row overrides these values in variable `name1` and `name2`. This happens till the last row, that will be the values in `name1` and `name2`.

What you should do is create a `ArrayList` instead of the two variables. In the while loop you add them to those lists.

```
// put this instead of your string name1 and name2 declarations.
ArrayList<string> userNames = new ArrayList<string();
ArrayList<string> firstNames = new ArrayList<string>();

// replace your while loop with this
while (rs.next()) {
    userNames.add(rs.getString("username"));
    firstNames.add(rs.getString("fName"));
}
```

Now you got all the usernames and firstnames in a list. 
You can print them by using this code:

```
 for (int i=0; i < userNames.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(userNames.get(i));
     System.out.println(firstNames.get(i));
 }
```